Processing command output on batch before command finished
I try to print time of command output(ping as example).
echo([!time!] start
for /f "usebackq delims= eol=" %%A in (`ping ::1`) do (
  echo([!time!] __ %%A
)
echo([!time!] finish

but as result I got
[12:37:08.78] start
[12:37:12.04] __ Pinging ::1 with 32 bytes of data:
[12:37:12.04] __ Reply from ::1: time<1ms
[12:37:12.04] __ Reply from ::1: time<1ms
[12:37:12.04] __ Reply from ::1: time<1ms
[12:37:12.04] __ Reply from ::1: time<1ms
[12:37:12.04] __ Ping statistics for ::1:
[12:37:12.04] __     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
[12:37:12.04] __ Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
[12:37:12.04] __     Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
[12:37:12.04] finish

look like cycle start work only after command finished.
Is there a way to process command output before command finished?

The FOR/F can not be used for asynchronous processing.
But it can be solved by using two threads and a pipe.
The producer_thread outputs to a file and the consumer_thread reads all the data with set /p and stops when it finds an "EOF" string.
To differentiate between the real "EOF" and an "EOF" from program output, the program output is piped through FIND to prefix each line with a line number.
The multiple for /L %%n in (1,1,256) do are used to build an (nearly) infinite loop, but still to be able to exit the loop with a goto command (a really infinite loop can't be stopped with goto).
@echo off
REM *** Trampoline jump for function calls of the form ex. "C:\:functionName:\..\myBatch.bat"
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%L in ("%~0") DO goto :%%L

cd. > async.tmp

"%~d0\:producer_thread:\..\%~pnx0" >> async.tmp | "%~d0\:consumer_thread:\..\%~pnx0" < async.tmp
echo END
exit /b

:producer_thread
(
    ping ::1 -n 3
    echo Test a single EOT
    echo EOT
    echo Some other output
) | find /n /v ""
(echo EOF)
exit /b

:consumer_thread
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo([!time!] start
for /L %%n in (1,1,256) do for /L %%n in (1,1,256) do for /L %%n in (1,1,256) do for /L %%n in (1,1,256) do (
  set "line="
  set /p "line="
  if "!line!" == "EOF" goto :exit_loop
  if defined line (
    set "line=!line:*]=!"
    echo([!time!] __ !line!
  )
)
:exit_loop
echo([!time!] finish
exit /b


Thanks for solution, it really works. But can you provide more explanation, why need intermediate file and "almost infinite loop". I understand (with experiment) that is necessary, but I don't understand why.

@darkrip the intermediate file is needed since batch has many significant limitations when it come to asynchrony. Batch scripts, by design, don't efficiently support inter-process communication, so the best way to share data between the two threads is to store the output of the producer in a file. The file also doubles as a sort of buffer or pipe, allowing the producer to write to the file while the consumer simultaneously reads the lines from it via set /p.

As for the "almost infinite loop", it's mainly used so that the script has a natural limit to it's iterations instead of running forever in the case that the exit condition for the loop is never reached (ex., if some error happened with ping in my script, it would loop infinitely).
And if you are curious, for /L %%n in (1,1,256) do for /L %%n in (1,1,256) do for /L %%n in (1,1,256) do for /L %%n in (1,1,256) ends up being 4,294,967,296 iterations. (256^4)

@gmifflen Not quite, the loop is not designed to limit it's iterations, actually the 4 for-loops allow a quick end with a goto :label. With only one loop up to 4 billion, the goto :label would take over an hour.  A real infinite loop like FOR /L %%# in ( )  cannot be interrupted at all by a GOTO

When you use for /f the loop waits until the command—in this case ping ::1—completes before it starts iterating through it's output, making it so that the loop will only get the output for the command after it has fully finished executing.
This is what causes the timestamps to be static, because the loop doesn't run until ping has completed, so you're getting the same timestamp for every iteration. To process the output while it's still running you'll have to read the input in real-time which Batch isn't very good at.
One nice trick we can use is the using start command to launch ping asynchronously and redirect the output to a temp file that we can continuously read in.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "tempfile=%temp%\temp.txt"

echo([!time!]) start
> "tempfile" echo. 

:: start ping in the background and send it's outputs to tempfile
start "" /b cmd /c ""ping ::1" > "%tempfile%""
set "last_line="

:loop
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%tempfile%") do (
        if "%%a" neq "!lastline!" (
            set "last_line=%%a"
            echo([!time!]) __ !last_line!
        )
    )

    findstr /c:"Ping statistics" "%tempfile%" >nul && goto :done

    :: small delay to avoid excessive cpu usage
    timeout /t 1 >nul
goto :loop

:done
echo([!time!]) finish
del "%tempfile%"

While my script is only psuedo-real-time with it's processing, it is much simpler than @jeb's genuine real-time processing, plus, it requires just a single thread instead of two.
I would recommend @jeb's producer-consumer script if you need reliable and actually asynchronous real-time processing. I didn't think of using this approach, and after seeing his script, it's definitely better for all but the most basic scenarios, but hey, that's where my simpler script would be more than sufficient :)

Although the solution requires an asynchronous execution of two threads, that can be assembled via a start command or via a pipe as shown in the other answers, there is a simpler method to write the required code. The keypoint is to use a goto command to assemble the output loop instead of a for:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Jump to the part indicated by first parameter
if "%~1" neq "" goto %1

rem/ > pipefile.txt
set "line="

echo [!time!] start
( ( ping ::1 -n 3 | find /N /V "") & echo []:EOF ) >> pipefile.txt | "%~F0" ShowPipe < pipefile.txt
echo [!time!] finish
goto :EOF


:ShowPipe
   set /P "line="
   if not defined line goto ShowPipe
   set "line=!line:*]=!"
   if "!line!" == ":EOF " goto :EOF
   echo [!time!] __ !line!
   set "line="
goto ShowPipe


You probably want the line if "!line!" == ":EOF " goto :EOF before set "line=!line:*]=!" to distinguish between process data and the real EOF. And change it to if "!line!" == "[]:EOF " goto :EOF

@jeb, Yes, This is a good idea! :)
